# How to configure NUnit TestResult output to include Expected Result and Actual Result

Tags: nunit

I am using NUnit: 2.6.4.14350 version. The output generated from NUnit doesnot have the ExpectedResult attribute value and ActaulResult attribute value for each test-case. Hence forth, I want to include them in the NUnit TestResult output. 
Current Output : 
"test-case name="MyTestClass.TC-40" description=" SUM of Two Numbers :SUM(2,3)" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.347" asserts="1""

Desired Output:
"test-case name="MyTestClass.TC-40" description=" SUM of Two Numbers :SUM(2,3)" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.347" asserts="1" expectedresult="5" actualresult="5" "

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

There is no capability in NUnit to add attributes or elements to the XML result. You would have to modify NUnit to do this.

If you use an equality constraint, the error message contains both the expected and actual values. Normally, there is no message for success but you can use Assert.Success to create one.

You could request a new feature for a future version of NUnit, of course.

Comment: Thanks Charlie for the input.